# Using SUBSTRING and RTRIM Together

Tags: sql-server-2016, substring, string-manipulation, trim

I have a VARCHAR field that contains a city and a 2 digit state abbreviation, but there tends to be leading and trailing spaces in the field.  I need to parse out the City and State Abbrev into separate fields. Currently I just have this to parse out the State, but I have no idea how to handle the City

```
RIGHT(RTRIM(alt.Address),2)
```

Comment: Is there a delimiter between City and State like a comma? Or a space between? And is it consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select right(rtrim(alt.Address),2),
   rtrim(left(ltrim(alt.Address),len(ltrim(rtrim(alt.Address))) - 2))
```

A slight variation on the second expression (city), which works the same but uses fewer `ltrim`/`rtrim` calls (which makes it more concise, albeit not necessarily clearer; it depends on how explicit you prefer the logic to be):

```
select right(rtrim(alt.Address),2),
   ltrim(rtrim(left(alt.Address,len(alt.Address) - 2)))
```

You can play with both options in [this live demo at dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=792bd0d3927b692d97ee48e6f27b239a).

Comment: You can make the second expression simpler: `left(alt.Address, len(alt.Address) - 2)`. Apply `ltrim` and/or `rtrim` to the result of `left` if necessary. [That works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07d0b12a56344d2a237783433d09cbcf) because `len` ignores trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I was not aware len() ignores the trailing spaces. However wouldn't you still need a ltrim() on the first parameter to left ? In the case of leading spaces.

Comment: As I said, you can apply either `ltrim` or `rtrim`, or both, after applying the `left`, i.e. to the result of `left`.

Comment: Additionally, there actually ARE going to be spaces between the City and State that will need to be dealt with

Comment: Yup my mistake, I just ran a test after re-reading your comment and realized, thanks!

Comment: This actually still works with spaces in between city and state abbreviation, give it a shot.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the second option, as it's just a variation on your solution. If you don't like it, feel free to roll back, I don't mind, cheers